# Linking Number and Green Theorem

Tags: knot-theory, greens-function

I try to solve an equation as $$ Lk(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{\beta}^{}\int_{\alpha}^{} \frac{p-p'}{||p-p'||^{3}}\cdot dp \times dp'=4\pi m$$ and we know that $$ \frac{p-p'}{||p-p'||^{3}}\cdot dp \times dp' = det((p-p'),dp,dp')$$ thus I converted the equation to   $$ Lk(\alpha,\beta)=\int_{\beta}^{}\int_{\alpha}^{}\frac{det((p-p'),dp,dp')}{||p-p'||^{3}}  $$ I am studying with 3 dimension but I do not know how to write the dp  and dp' with 3 components in determinant. Thanks to help.

Comment: I found a article for it. You can reach it from here. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/ricca.pdf <cite authors="Ricca, Renzo L.; Nipoti, Bernardo">_Ricca, Renzo L.; Nipoti, Bernardo_, [**Gauss’ linking number revisited**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218216511009261), J. Knot Theory Ramifications 20, No. 10, 1325-1343 (2011). [ZBL1230.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1230.57009).</cite>

Comment: I see a deletion brigade deleted your self-answer, which is unfortunate since the paper you cite certainly answers the question, and now no one can see it. I'll put the citation here until we can hopefully undelete your answer (I think it should be enough to mention where in the paper answers the question). <cite authors="Ricca, Renzo L.; Nipoti, Bernardo">_Ricca, Renzo L.; Nipoti, Bernardo_, [**Gauss’ linking number revisited**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S0218216511009261), J. Knot Theory Ramifications 20, No. 10, 1325-1343 (2011). [ZBL1230.57009](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1230.57009).</cite>

Comment: @KyleMiller (1) Name calling is a violation of the CoC (referring to others as "the deletion brigade" is unfriendly.  (2) Answers on Math SE should be self-contained answers.  The deleted answer contains several links, but no explanation of how those links address the question here.  Hence the answer was deleted as  "link-only" answer, which is a good and valid reason to delete an answer.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Sorry, I didn't mean for it to come across as name-calling; I just meant it seemed to be deleted by an organized group of people. Regarding the answer, while it could definitely be improved, I believe this is one of those cases where the best thing to do is just read the paper, since the paper answers it, and the paper will always be accessible (link-rot is of absolutely no concern). I also believe it is unfriendly to delete a self-answer by a new contributor.

Comment: @KyleMiller Again, questions on Math SE need to be as self-contained as possible.  If the best possible answer to a question is "read this paper", with no other insight or commentary, then the question probably isn't a good fit for the Q&A format of SE.  Math SE is not a content aggregator.  Even questions tagged [tag:reference-request] are expected to include *some* commentary.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Right, I'm familiar with the standards. I feel that this case is special for a few reasons (1) it's a self-answer by a new contributor, so we shouldn't just delete the answer the first day it is written, (2) it's a high-quality paper (I've read it before), and one can see the answer around equation 3.7, and (3) the primary reason for avoiding link-only answers is link rot, and this is a document with an assigned DOI -- it will *always* be available. Maybe the question itself isn't a good fit; that's fair, and it's more basic vector calculus rather than knot theory per se.

Comment: @XanderHenderson If (1) did not hold, then I would agree with deletion, to be clear. I also think that (3) is a strong case against this being deleted as a "link-only" answer -- context makes an answer good, but having no context doesn't make it bad if the link is stable. At this point I'll leave things to Ahmet, if they want to make their answer better to make the situation less ambiguous.

Comment: @KyleMiller We must hold *all* users to the same standards.  There is nothing "unfriendly" nor "unkind" about universally applying the same standards to everyone.  The only way in which a new user should be treated differently is that new users ought to have the rules explained to them, which I did in my original reply to you (which also pinged the original asker).